# Summation to Infinity Query

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

How would I go about solving
$\sum_{n=1000}^\infty n^3$

I thought about possibly making two separate summations?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? The series will diverge. Are you trying to prove it diverges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean $$\sum_{n=1000}^\infty n^3$$ then $$\sum_{n=1000}^\infty n^3>\sum_{n=1000}^\infty 1=+\infty.$$

Comment: Yeah sorry about that thanks!

Comment: @Jan You are welcome!

Comment: @Jan If this answered your question, you should mark the answer as accepted and upvote it too if you feel like it.